# Add Task doesnot working in django in ToDo List

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

**this is task_list.html**

```html
<!--if we didnt create this tasklis.html we get error becoz as said in views .py it looks for tempate
we diidnt cdreated any list on template et-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>To Do List By Manasi</title>
</head>
<body>
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>{{ request.user }}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
<hr>


<h2>WELCOME To My To List! </h2>
<a href="{% url 'create-task' %}">Add task</a>
<table bgcolor="yellow" align="center" border="2px">
  <tr>
    <th>Task Name</th><th> Task Details</th><th>Edit Task</th><th align="center">Delete Task</th>
  </tr>
  {% for task in tasks %} <!--for task in object_list %}this is when we havent created objet context list yet in view.pywhen view.py only contains model=Task-->
  <tr><td align="center">{{task.title}}</td><td align="center"><a href=" {% url 'task' task.id %}">View</a></td><td align="center"><a href=" {% url 'update-task' task.id %}">Edit</a></td>
  <td align="center"><a href=" {% url 'delete-task' task.id %}">Delete Task</a></td></tr> <!--i think this 'task' in url is context_objct_name in views.py but its false-->

  {% empty %} <!--this is django template format for empty condition likewise ele etc.-->
  <tr><td>No item</td></tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
**this is task_form.html for add task ie.create task**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create task Form</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Create task form</h1>
  <a href="{% url 'tasks' %}">Go Back</a>
  <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
  </form>
  <!--django creates form for user  model automatically on the basis of model attributes we provides while creating a form-->
  <!--you wiill see the boxes an all is like a admin panel have but here is in horizotal manner so put as_p for vertical-->

</body>

</html>
```

I am creating a project "TO Do App" using django in pycharm.I created model for task first then create a taskview and detail vview and still here things are woked.then i created Create view and template for add task and things were worked. then created deleteview things are ok even i created login view. and then i created logout view,User registration.as i create user registration sucessfully i tried by registeriing for different users and creating their own tasklist but now add task is not working.
able to click on add task and afte filling details and presiing submit button i couldnt able to see the tasks in tasklist.

i can see these added tasks in admin panel but i cant see tasklist in list view template after creating logout and login and user registration.

also i couldnt see any errror after submiting task.

here is task_form.html page to after pressing add task in task_list.html it redirects to task_form.html

views.py screenshot 1:
[image: views.py screenshot 1]

viwes.py screenshot 2:
[image: viwes.py screenshot 2]

Comment: [Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=DO%20NOT%20post%20images%20of%20code%2C%20data%2C%20error%20messages%2C%20etc.)

Comment: i have tried to  post code directly. but it showing error

Answer (score 0):

if your all the views like registration , login are working perfectly then there could be an error in the views where you render your `task_list.html`

can you share your view which renders your `task_list.html` and model of the to_do list

Comment: hey thanks for this. as i removed get_context_data function from TaskList view then all tasks are shown which i have added but all tasks are showing to all users because of removal of get_context_data function

Comment: i think now the problem either lies where you are making ORM request to database or in models ..... but more likely in ORM request

Comment: i didnt understand exactly whta do u want to say. Is there any another way to use  get_context_data function?